# Rails slow terminal execution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server, terminal

I'm running a rails app, everything is working fine when launching a server, a console or sidekiq.
But the problem I got is, everything running in my consoles are very slow. It isn't relative to SQL requests as all is working fine on my coworkers laptops and there are quick.

We have a seed in a job and every line of pid is very slow to appear, like each entry takes time. So the proccess is very slow, and I don't manage to understand why.
It's the same on my server for some pages, the terminal lines take time to appear and is very slow

I tried to uninstall postgres and many other gems and services but nothing worked.
I also reboot my whole computer but I'm still facing the problem : Everything is slow to execute in my consoles. It's almost impossible to work with this

When I try to access a page that would normally load in 200ms, I need more than a minute to load the view
[image: terminal]

Comment: Unfortunately, since this problem is device-specific it is highly unlikely you get any meaningful help until you do some legwork first and narrow down the problem.

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov I've updated my post with a picture. My view rendering is very long to load, I see some (very simple) methods that take long time to be checked when accessing a page in my server